# Strange behaviour with decrement operator

Tags: c++

My code is meant to print an array in reverse but for some reason the decrement operator isn't working as expected. According to my understanding `--var` decrements the variable `var` before anything is done to it while `var--` decrements the variable `var` after an operation has been completed such as a `for` loop.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int arrLen;
    int arr[4];
    scanf("%d\n %d %d %d %d", &arrLen, &arr[0], &arr[1], &arr[2], &arr[3]);
    for (; arrLen >= 0; --arrLen)
        printf("%d %d\n", arr[arrLen], arrLen);

    return 0;
}
```

And here are my results (the right value in the output is the decremented variable, I added it to check):

```
0 4
2 3
3 2
4 1
1 0
```

Without the decremented variable being printed it should be:

`0 2 3 4 1`

Here are my expected results:

`2 3 4 1`

Comment: Why use "\n" in scanf () function?

Comment: @M.SChaudhari Checking for an int followed by a \n

Comment: How did this question get 3 up votes I do not understand....

Comment: @ZivS No point asking irrelevant questions, it got up voted because people found it useful.

Comment: @JamesBalajan, It was not a question. If anything a rhetorical one. IMO you did not show any effort in debugging\understanding the code or the way `for` or `operator--` work. Also, the question itself could have been phrased better. I have no problem with not knowing something but the internet is full of other people who asked this question and other questions on S.O get down voted for much less

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason this is not behaving as you expect is because of how `for` loops work.

```
for (statement_1; condition; statement_2) {
    body;
}
```

`statement_1` is called only once before the loop begins.

`condition` is evaluated at the beginning of each pass in the loop. If it is true, `body` is evaluated. If not the loop exits.

`statement_2` is evaluated **after** the `body` at the end of each pass in the loop, just before re-evaluating the `condition`.

So while `--var` does decrement and return the decremented value, it is only actually called after the body of your `for` loop each time it is run.

This means that `--var` and `var--` will have the same effect on the behaviour of a `for` loop when part of `statement_2`.

To produce your desired behaviour you could change your for loop to this:

```
while (--arrLen >= 0)
    printf("%d %d\n", arr[arrLen], arrLen);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following line. I think your for loop was not proper.

```
for (; arrLen > 0; --arrLen) printf("%d %d\n", arr[arrLen - 1], arrLen);
```

It will now have the following output

```
2 4
3 3
4 2
1 1
```

Comment: That'll work but it doesn't address the underlying misunderstanding about how `for` works